# How to insert the data from the textbox and checkbox with a stored procedure into SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

This my code in vb.net, but when I run this code, it does not respond

```
If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
     TextBox30.Enabled = True
     .Parameters.Add("MOD3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBox30.Text
Else
     TextBox30.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: Sorry - what?!?!? This doesn't seem like a very complete code listing.... please provide **more and meaningful** information about your issue!

Comment: and also, state what went wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
         TextBox30.Enabled = True
         Dim cmd as new SqlCommand 
         cmd.CommandText = "your store procedure name here.."
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoreProcedure
         cmd.Connection = con //your connection string object
         cmd.Parameters.Add("MOD3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBox30.Text
         con.Open()
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         con.Close()
        Else
            TextBox30.Enabled = False
        End If
```